# My query takes too long to complete

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have a query that is taking to long to finish in Oracle. It ran for a few hours before I killed it.  Is there any way I can speed it up?

Here is my query:

```
select distinct(random_selection.randnum), 
    random_selection.dropper_id, 
    random_selection.ozip3 
from random_selection 
where random_selection.dropper_id is not null 
and random_selection.quarter = 121
and (random_selection.dropper_id, random_selection.randnum, random_selection.quarter) in 
    (select forecast_entry.dropper, forecast_entry.rand_num, production_weeks.yyq 
    from forecast_entry, production_weeks 
    where forecast_entry.week = production_weeks.production_week 
    and production_weeks.project_cd = 'EXFC' 
    and production_weeks.yyq >= 121)

union 

select distinct(random_selection.randnum), 
    dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id, 
    random_selection.ozip3 
from random_selection, dropper_city_brk_2, dropper 
where random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3 
and dropper.dropper_id = dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id 
and dropper.active = 1 
and dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002 
and random_selection.quarter = 121
and random_selection.dropper_id is null 
and (random_selection.dropper_id, random_selection.randnum, random_selection.quarter) in 
    (select forecast_entry.dropper, forecast_entry.rand_num, production_weeks.yyq 
    from forecast_entry, production_weeks 
    where forecast_entry.week = production_weeks.production_week 
    and production_weeks.project_cd = 'EXFC' 
    and production_weeks.yyq >= 121)
```

Query explained:

the main objective is to get all of the randnum, dropper_id, and ozip3 from random_selection table that are not in the forecast_entry table and are in yyq 121 and have a project code of EXFC.  yyq is retrieved from the production_weeks table by associating week and production week. Some dropper_id are null so we need to pull that data from the dropper_city_brk_2 table by associating ozip3 and zip3.  We dont want dropper_id that are inactive so they must have active equal 1, this is by associating the dropper table.

hope this helps

Comment: You should include your table schema in the question and any indices you have set up.

Comment: This is the biggest SQL query I have seen in my life :) Will have to take small breaks for reading it

Comment: I have seen bigger......

Comment: In addition to showing your schema, show the output from EXPLAIN PLAN

Comment: Mike, we're not all psychic, you'll need to post table structures, indexes, table sizes and explain plans for us to help you. Also check your database statistics are up to date.

Comment: Try asking here instead: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It takes a long time to read, too!  Readability could benefit from table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the commenters that you should provide at least the output of explain plain in a gist, otherwise it is very hard to help.

You are running the forecast_entry, production_weeks sub query twice. You may get better performance by using CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE to compute that query once.

You are using "where X in (subquery)", which is often less efficient than doing a join. Instead of using the IN clause here you can do INNER JOIN on the temporary table that I just suggested.

You can switch to UNION ALL if you can tolerate duplicates or if you know that there are no duplicates. UNION ALL requires less work for the DB than UNION.

Finally, you can pull this apart in to three pieces and test each separately. The pieces are the sub query and the two queries that you're unioning. That might help you narrow down which parts are slow.